# RealmSwift 3.0.2 and Swift4 issue

Tags: realm, cocoapods, swift4

Using RealmSwift-3.0.2, Cocoapods-1.3.1, Swift-4.0.3, iOS-11.2, XCode-9.2

I am trying to create a Realm object (as I always did the last three years).
But since Swift4, something seems off !

I get the following Error-message:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Below is my code:

```
import RealmSwift

var rlm: Realm?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // instantiate Realm
    self.rlm = try? Realm()  // !!!!!!!!!!! Here is where the above error happens...
}
```

My PodFile looks like this:

```
project 'MyApp.xcodeproj'
workspace 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
platform :ios, '11.2'
inhibit_all_warnings!

source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
      pod 'RealmSwift'
end

target 'MyApp' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyAppTests' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'MyAppUITests' do
    shared_pods
end
```

Any help appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error:

My Realm object had a wrong primary-key (i.e. type-fault !!)

```
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "myID" // !!!! Was "mID" :/ :/
}
```

After correcting the type-fault, it all works again nicely !

(...would be nice if the RealmSwift error message was somehow more explanatory...)